# map parent Id to all its child records ( getting Error: Incompatible value type )

Tags: apex, class, map, visualforce

I have below snippet of apex class where I face below error to compile. Can someone please help?

**Error**

> Incompatible value type Survey_Question_vod__c for
>   Map>

**Code Snippet**

```
  List<Survey_Question_vod__c> oldques = [select Id, Name,Question_vod__c,Survey_vod__c from Survey_Question_vod__c where Survey_vod__c in : oldsurvey];
    List<Survey_Question_vod__c> newques = [select Id, Name,Question_vod__c,Survey_vod__c from Survey_Question_vod__c where Survey_vod__c in : newsurvey];
    Map<Id,Survey_Question_vod__c> oldmapques = new map<Id,Survey_Question_vod__c>();
    for(Survey_Question_vod__c sq: oldques.values())
    {oldmapques.put(sq.Question_vod__c,sq);

    }  

     Map<Id,List<Survey_Question_vod__c>> newmapques = new map<Id,List<Survey_Question_vod__c>>();
    for(Survey_Question_vod__c sq: newques)
    {newmapques.put(sq.Question_vod__c,sq);

    }
```

Comment: you map should be `Map<Id,Survey_Question_vod__c>` and iterate over `oldques.values()`

Comment: But oldques is a list of Survey_Question_vod__c. It throws now this error - Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [List<Survey_Question_vod__c>].values()

Comment: Do you want a list or single record as the value?

Comment: Please find the updated snippet.

Comment: @SFDC_Learner oldques is a list but you want to store each record from the list in the map, so each record will be a value and record id will be the key.

Comment: @SFDC_Learner Can you tell us what exactly you want to store in the map?

Comment: Well for list there is no method values().your first for loop must be like this: `for(Survey_Question_vod__c sq: oldques`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Updated

Since `oldques` is a list just iterate over it and assign it to map

### Completed code

```
Map<Id,Survey_Question_vod__c> oldmapques = new map<Id,Survey_Question_vod__c>();
 for(Survey_Question_vod__c sq: oldques)
 {  
       oldmapques.put(sq.Question_vod__c,sq);

}
```

---

### Updates

Looks like you want to map parentId to all child records

```
Map<Id,List<Survey_Question_vod__c>> newmapques = new map<Id,List<Survey_Question_vod__c>>();
    for(Survey_Question_vod__c sq: newques)
    {
        if(!newmapques.containsKey(sq.Question_vod__c))
            newmapques.put(sq.Question_vod__c, new list<Survey_Question_vod__c>{sq});
        else
            newmapques.get(sq.Question_vod__c).add(sq);
    }
```